# Trying to backup MacOS on a USB key get error 254?

Tags: backup, usb

I'm trying to backup my MacOS computer onto an USB key, and when I run the restore command from the Disk Utility app, I get an error 254 :

```
Validating target...
Validating source...
Source volumt format on device "/dev/disk0" is not valid for restoring
Could not validate source - error 254
The operation failed
```

For information, the title is really odd since it shows **Restoring to "My Usb Key" from "(null)"** (sorry the text is approximative (it's originally in French), but the main point here is the "from null")

What is wrong with my usb key? (it's a 8Gb, Apple asked for a "more than 1gb").

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've selected the volume, not the disk, in the list on the left. I saw the same error when I tried using the disk selected.  Also note, making a copy of a booted system may not produce the best results...

Comment: I tried with various item (volumes, disk, etc) with different results, but never successful. I finally followed a documentation from Apple https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372 and this worked successfully well :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I tried to Restore (clone) my Mac startup Volume to a new SSD.
@MacManager's answer got me in the right direction:

1. Erase (format) destination Disk and use a Volume Format supported by Mac i.e. Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
2. Restore to destination Volume created in previous step